# How to check whether a checkbox is checked or not in Ext JS 3 when 'name' attribute is used

Tags: checkbox, extjs3, name-attribute

I have checkboxes created in Ext JS. When defined with 'id' attribute, I'm able to check whether its checked or not, but this is resulting in a different functionality failure.

I want to check whether the checkbox is checked or not when those checkboxes are created using 'name' attribute instead of 'id' attribute.

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ref attribute instead of id  - http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-ref

Comment: Thanks, I've figured it out with the help of some senior colleagues.
Yes, the ref attribute worked perfectly :)